# importing undefined react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the following two ways to declare a react component called `DashboardComponent`.

```
export default function DashboardComponent() {
    return <div>test</div>
}

export default class DashboardComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>test</div>
    }
}
```

When tested these two I commented the other one.

The problem is that when I test this with

```
import DashboardComponent from './main/dashboard-component';
console.log(DashboardComponent);
```

the first one return a `function` and the second one returns `undefined`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you post full file ./main/dashboard-component?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had a circular dependency.

I have a file with routes and here I was importing `DashboardComponent`

```
import DashboardComponent from './main/dashboard-component';

const routes = [
    {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: DashboardComponent,
        icon: 'home'
    },
...
]
```

Also I had included routes file in `DashboardComponent`. This was from my previous tests. Removing the routes import from `DashboardComponent` solved the problem.